# First SQL Database not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a personal project of mine and I am accepting a name and email so I created a database called:

emailtemp with columns of "name" and "email"

[PHPMyAdmin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjyiZ.png)

HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" action="connect.php" class="contact100-form validate-form">
    <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-10 validate-input" data-validate = "Name is required">
            <input class="s2-txt1 placeholder0 input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Name">
            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-20 validate-input" data-validate = "Email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
        <input class="s2-txt1 placeholder0 input100" type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <button class="flex-c-m s2-txt2 size4 bg1 bor1 hov1 trans-04">
            Subscribe
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("mysql.*****.net","*****","****>","emailtemp");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (customerName, customerEmail)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[emailAddress]')";

?>
```

Based off everything I read and looked at it it should work but after I click "subscribe" it pulls up connect.php and says "is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Is there a way to have this process in the background and stay on the same page and just say successful?

Comment: the http 500 error is because of a PHP error you are missing a `)` in this line `mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (customerName, customerEmail)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[emailAddress]')";`

Comment: And there is an error with your question description. You created a database `emailtemp` and within this database you added a table `posts (customerName, customerEmail)` not `emailtemp with columns of "name" and "email"`

Comment: So is my code wrong for trying to insert into the table of 'w/ column of "name" and " email"? Looks like I added the ) and now the PHP page just show blanks but didn't insert anything into the database.

Comment: Did you put correct values in the connection string ? Please check with it .

Comment: Oh forgot I took that from my editor and not take it out haha. Thanks for fixing it for me!

Comment: Your question "have this process in the background" is inconsistent with the _information in your question_ about getting a 500 error.  Focus on solving the 500 error....

Comment: I rolled the question back to a previous revision. You went and totally changed the original question. That isn't how things are done here.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("mysql.*****.net","*****","****>","emailtemp");

if ($stmt = $mysqli_prepare($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (customerName, customerEmail) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['username'],$_POST['emailAddress']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: I tried that because mine wasn't working and gave me HTTP 500 error again.

Comment: Maybe i have the actual database setup up wrong so I added a screenshot of PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like you're missing a `)` at the end of your `mysqli_query()` call.
2. If your DB is really like this:

   > emailtemp with columns of "name" and "email"

.. then you should match those in your query:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO emailtemp (name, email)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[emailAddress]')");
```

3. Recommended to check for user/email first, if they're somehow empty that will throw an exception.

like this:

```
$username = $_POST[username];
$email = $_POST[emailAddress];
if ($username && $email) {
  // stuff here
} else {
  // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: I added how I have the database setup to my original post pretty sure I described it correctly. Also I shouldn't have to check for username and email because the HTML form checked that already..

Comment: I see the update now - looks like the table is called `subscribed_users`, not  `post`? Can you try:
`mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO subscribed_users (name, email)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[emailAddress]')");`

Comment: @CooperH can you try `subscribed_users` instead of `posts` or `emailtemp` for the table name?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the mysqli_query function with an ) and you forgot the brackets around username and emailAdress

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (customerName, customerEmail)
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[emailAddress]')");
```

Also this code makes you vulnerable to an [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Users can inject other commands to the SQL server and they get executed with admin rights.

You can use PDO, a secure implementation of SQL in PHP (if used right of course)

In your example it would be:

```
    $dbhost = "your-host";
    $dbname = "your-db-name";
    $dbusername = "your-username";
    $dbpassword = "your-password";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);

    $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (customerName, customerEmail)
VALUES (:username, :emailAddress");
    $statement->execute(array(
        "username" => $_POST['username'],
        "emailAdress" => $_POST['emailAdress']
    ));
```

Comment: So I did what you said with the exception of "posts" changed to emailtemp" and it did not give me any errors but did not post anything to the database.

Comment: Your code seems to work best but still doesn't post to database.

Comment: hmm, are you sure that the username and the password are right?

Comment: OK I fixed something in the code, try to the remove the , after $_POST['emailAdress']

Comment: did this fix your problem @CooperH

Comment: Not yet, I am working with yours still messing around to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Ok so after looking at this for a little bit longer I think I figured out the problem... The columns are "name" and "email" should should we be posting to like: "emailAdress" => $_POST['email']

Comment: change "emailAdress" => $_POST['emailAdress']

Comment: it is build by "columnName" => variable

Comment: do you have discord or teamviewer?

Comment: I do, send me an email I'll get you connected over! Your the man! noreturns@live.com